# Check if value is not equal in when()-statement

Tags: kotlin

Is it possible to test a String for not being equal in a when-statement?

This is of course perfectly possible with a simpel if statement:

```
val storedValue = sharedPreferences.getString(identifier, NOT_SET)
if (storedValue != NOT_SET) {
    super.setValue(storedValue)
}
```

However, I like how `storedValue` is scoped inside of the when-statement in this snippet:

```
when (val storedValue = sharedPreferences.getString(identifier, NOT_SET)) {
    NOT_SET -> {}
    else -> super.setValue(storedValue)
}
```

The downfall is the empty code block for the `NOT_SET` entry.
Is it possible to combine these two?

I'd like to scope `storedValue` and get rid of empty code blocks. The result would be comparable to:

```
when (val storedValue = sharedPreferences.getString(identifier, NOT_SET)) {
    !NOT_SET -> super.setValue(storedValue)
}
```

Since SharedPreferences is part of the Android framework, this would another solution:

```
if (sharedPreferences.contains(identifier)) {
    super.setValue(sharedPreferences.getString(identifier, null))
}
```

However, the goal of my question is deeper understanding of the possibilities of Kotlin, for the sake of learning.

Comment: I'm afraid that is not supported by the language yet.. the alternative would be something like `when { storedValue != NOT_SET -> //do something }`, but that doesn't solve the scoping "issue"

Comment: Or I'd could scope it differently, with `with(sharedPreferences.getString(identifier, NOT_SET))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, negation is not directly supported like this in when statements (yet) even in Kotlin.

The most idiomatic way at the moment most probably is like:

```
val storedValue = sharedPreferences.getString(identifier, NOT_SET)
when {
    storedValue != "NOT_SET" -> super.setValue(storedValue)
}
```

Another working variant utilizing `!in` in when could be for example:

```
when (val storedValue = sharedPreferences.getString(identifier, NOT_SET)) {
     !in setOf("NOT_SET") -> super.setValue(storedValue)
}
```

And as both `!=` and`!in` will compare case sensitively, so would make sense to get the string like `sharedPreferences.getString(identifier, NOT_SET).toUpperCase()`, or use `equalsIgnoreCase` in the first variant.

Comment: Is `storedValue != NOT_SET` not allowed in the first snippet: it expects a String, where `storedValue != NOT_SET` is a boolean.  But certainly thanks!

Comment: Hehe, yes, you are right - updated (writing code without a compiler^^).